# Angular 2 Material 2 Slide Toggle Doesn't Seem to be working in Alpha 7 Error: Cannot find name 'HammerInput'

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I just upgraded to Alpha 7 and after upgrade Slide Toggle seems to be broken.

When I compile my project in Visual Studio 2015 I receive the below errors:

```
Error       Build:Cannot find name 'HammerInput'.   node_modules\@angular2-material\slide-toggle\slide-toggle.d.ts  67  

Error   TS2304  Cannot find name 'HammerInput'. TypeScript Virtual Projects node_modules\@angular2-material\slide-toggle\slide-toggle.d.ts  67
```

Apparently it seems that the below line is causing the problem in slide-toggle.d.ts:

```
_onDrag(event: HammerInput): void;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you everyone installing typings through command:

```
npm install --save hammerjs @types/hammerjs
```

and then importing it in main file solved the issue.:

```
/// <reference path="../typings/globals/hammerjs/index.d.ts" />
```

For more details, please have a look at:

https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/977#issuecomment-238946558

Comment: better add `"types": ["hammerjs"]` to tsconfig.json isntead of putting the reference path in the template